# How to save a chain of scopes to reuse it multiple times

Tags: pointers, orm, scope, yii

The way I'd like to write code:

```
$chain = Articles::model()->visible()->childOf($teleshow_id);
echo $chain->count( $criteria ); 
// 1st echo - will write the amount of visible articles, 
// which are children of $teleshow_id

echo $chain->count( $criteria ); 
// this echo will write the amount of all articles
```

But I'd like to get identical results of `echo`s.

Is there any solution to keep $chain persistent ( to work with not a pointer to  Articles::model()->visible()->childOf($teleshow_id) )

Comment: I can't say that i got your question 100% but as far as i did i think you need some sort of cashing in order to store the result or the count of the named scope filter http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.overview

Comment: No, no. The idea is not in repeating of the same action for number of times, but in possibility of using  $chain object more than once. For ex. I do something like $chain->count(); then I do some paging manipulation and then I do $chain->findAll(); I dont like to build new $chain-similiar object with all list of scopes to call it's findAll method.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```
// in your Articles class
private $_chain;

public function getChain($teleshow_id = false)
{
    if(!isset($this->_chain))
    {
        $chain = Articles::model()->visible()->childOf($teleshow_id);
    }
    return $this->_chain;
}
```

and then call it from your controller like this:

```
$model = new Articles();
$chain = $model->getChain($teleshow_id);

$model->chain->count();
```

or something similar.  You may need to mess with making getChain static if you want to make your calls easier, but you should be able to get started with that.